# Having trouble with radio selection and pulling data from radio button for PHP

Tags: php, mysql

The following is the error I receive:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
> access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'WHERE customerID = '1098'' at line 5 in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab06\tech_support\customer_manager\update_customer.php:55
> Stack trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab06\tech_support\customer_manager\update_customer.php(55):
> PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main} thrown in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\4090_TamezP_Lab06\tech_support\customer_manager\update_customer.php
> on line 55

```
<?php
 require('../model/database.php');
    // require('../model/product_db.php');

    $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
    if ($action === NULL) {
        $action = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'action');
        if ($action === NULL) {
            $action = 'update_customer';
        }
    }

    if ($action == '../update_customer') {
        include('../update_customer.php');
    }

    $customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $first_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'firstName');
    $last_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'lastName');
    $address = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'address');
    $city = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'city');
    $state = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'state');
    $postal_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'postalCode');
    $countryCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'countryCode');
    $phone = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'phone');
    $email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');
    $password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password');
    // INSERT CODE HERE TO add a variable named $gender to receive the value passed from the selected radio     button on the update_customer_form.php file
    $gender = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gender');
    // INSERT CODE HERE TO update the newly created gender field

    $query = 'UPDATE customers
                SET firstName = :firstName, lastName = :lastName, address = :address, city = :city,
                state = :state, postalCode = :postalCode, countryCode = :countryCode, phone =     :phone,
                email = :email, password = :password, gender = :gender,             
                WHERE customerID = :customer_id';
        
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':customer_id', $customer_id);
    $statement->bindValue(':firstName', $first_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':lastName', $last_name);
    $statement->bindValue(':address', $address);
    $statement->bindValue(':city', $city);
    $statement->bindValue(':state', $state);
    $statement->bindValue(':postalCode', $postal_code);
    $statement->bindValue(':countryCode', $countryCode);
    $statement->bindValue(':phone', $phone);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement->bindValue(':password', $password);
    // INSERT CODE HERE to bind the value of the gender variable
    $statement->bindValue(':gender', $gender);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->closeCursor();

    include('update_customer_form.php');
    ?>
```

Beginning PHP, MYSQL coder. I've looked online and tried a few variations of the radio button codes but nothing I have tried has worked. It looks pretty straight forward and I'm sure I'm missing something small but i've spent 3 hours trying and thought I'd go ahead and ask.

Comment: If you're just getting started with PHP and want to build applications, I'd strongly recommend looking at various [development frameworks](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) to see if you can find one that fits your style and needs. They come in various flavours from lightweight like [Fat-Free Framework](https://fatfreeframework.com/) to far more comprehensive like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/). These give you concrete examples to work from and guidance on how to write your code and organize your project's files.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing an access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Any modern [development framework](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with an [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: Hint: When MySQL gives you a specific spot in the query to look at, examine just a bit before that. In this case there's a spurious `,`.

Comment: I just removed it, thanks to tadman hint. Also please don't be rude, I said I was a beginner. The hint was exactly what I needed.

Comment: @JoséCarlosPHP Sometimes it's easy to overlook things, especially if you don't know where to look in the first place. Be kind.

Comment: @tadman, Pete and everyone, I'm sorry. But that error message telling what kind of error is and where to look... Surely next time Pete will debug better.